# I am facing following error "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

hi i am new flutter development and i'm facing error:

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'
```

in following lines image:

```
element.data()['image'],
name: element.data()['name'],
price: element.data()['price']
```

**please let me know if there is any solution**

```
List<FoodCategoriesModle> burgerCategoriesList = [];
   Future<void> getBurgerCategoriesList() async {
   List<FoodCategoriesModle> newBurgerCategoriesList = [];
   QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('foodcategories')
    .doc('8Dtfnhwbi1cDkCrX02rA')
    .collection('burger')
    .get();
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    FoodCategoriesModle burgerCategoriesModle = FoodCategoriesModle(
    image: element.data()['image'],
    name: element.data()['name'],
    price: element.data()['price'],);
    newBurgerCategoriesList.add(burgerCategoriesModle);
    burgerCategoriesList = newBurgerCategoriesList;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Learn about null safety in Flutter https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 0):

change those:

```
    image: element.data()['image'],
    name: element.data()['name'],
    price: element.data()['price'],);
```

with this:

```
    image: (element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)!['image'],
    name: (element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)!['name'],
    price: (element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)!['price'],);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `element.data()` you looking for may be null you need set default value for them like this:

```
image: (element.data() ?? {})['image'],
name: (element.data()?? {})['name'],
price: (element.data()?? {})['price'],);
```